# How to config basing condition in Spring IOC?

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I config IOC basing condition,like following:

```
<bean id="beanid" class="com...Class1" >
  <if var='xxx'>
    <property name="formView"
      value="RegistrationApprovalForm" />
  <else if var ='yyy'>
    <property name="formView"
      value="RegistrationApprovalForm1" />
</bean>
```

so I can put var in properties files,this will make configration easy.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more precision of what you want to achieve. It's a little bit confused.

Comment: Are you asking how you read in properties files and inject the values into your Spring app?  As @Mannekenpix said, your question is a little vague/confusing.

Comment: Hi,

I am trying to achieve this.                                     <bean id="beanid" class="com...Class1" >
<if var='xxx'>
<property name="formView"
value="RegistrationApprovalForm" />
<else if var ='yyy'>
<property name="formView"
value="RegistrationApprovalForm1" />
</bean>

Comment: Can you suggest if something similar is available in spring mvc.  @Mannekenpix

Comment: I still don't understand. You want to display a view based on a param?

Comment: yes. I want to redirect to the view based on the configuration using same controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

${ServiceMgmt.showEnabler}

```
</bean>
```

I want to redirect to the view based on configuration as below.

else

Is this possible with spring configuration??